# BUILD App después de compilar el FlexibleClient y crear un snapshot

Tags: android, genexus

Después de compilar el FlexibleClient en GX17 U3, al hacer un Build no toma la versión nueva.
Sigue tomando la versión 17.3 en lugar de la 17.3-SNAPHOT

Alguien sabe que tengo que modificar para que tome la ultima versión?

Comment: Juan, ¿por qué querrías compilar el flexible client? ¿Le estás haciendo cambios? Esos cambios se van a perder cuando actualices GeneXus. ¿Puedo preguntar qué es lo que quieres resolver? Gracias.

Comment: Las versiones release son fijas. Debes renombrar el archivo que recién compilaste como 17.3.(sobre escribir el de Genexus, realiza backup antes).

Comment: Modifico el flexible client, para que detecte las impresoras bluetooth. Si tengo claro que en cada upgrade esto se pierde y tengo que lograr compilar....  Agrego  major == BluetoothClass.Device.Major.IMAGING ||

Answer (score 0):

Bueno después de probar de todo  modifique el archivo project-params.gradle y logre que en lugar de generar un snaphot mantenga la misma versión.
Con eso quedo resuelto el incidente.